# Using for-each loop with a function that returns an iterator

Tags: java, foreach, iterator

How can I use a for each loop with a function that returns an iterator in Java? For example, I'd like to use a for-each loop for a function with this signature:

```
public Iterator<Integer> intIterator();
```

Is it possible or do I have to use a regular for-loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Java's for-each is defined to require an `Iterable`, and `Iterator`s aren't `Iterable`. This can be a pain if, say, you want to provide 3 kinds of iterator for a tree or forward and backward iterators over a data structure.

The easiest way is to use a regular for loop, but if you want, you can write a wrapper class, like so:

```
public class IteratorWrapper<E> implements Iterable<E> {
    private Iterator<E> iterator;

    public IteratorWrapper(Iterator<E> iterator) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return iterator;
    }

    // Static import the following method for less typing at the
    // call sites.
    public static <E> IteratorWrapper<E> wrapIter(Iterator<E> iterator) {
        return new IteratorWrapper<E>(iterator);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for-each` loop can only iterate over an array or an instance of `java.lang.Iterable`. you can not do it.

you can iterate like -

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = intIterator();
for (; iterator.hasNext();) {
    Integer type =  iterator.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use the iterator as other people have said.

Make another function :

```
public Iterable<Integer> intIterable() {
    return new Iterable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
                    return intIterator();
        }
    }
}
```

Use in for-each loop like

```
for ( Integer int : object.intIterable() ) {
}
```